# Can't start collpased div closed using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Having a little trouble, can't start the collapsed div closed, It starts opened. Some help would be appreciated

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-danger">
            <a class="card-link text-dark" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne2"><span class="fas fa-newspaper solid size-1x"></span> News</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne2" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
            Cras eu est tortor. Maecenas varius massa arcu, quis hendrerit nulla molestie id. Maecenas non lorem ex. Morbi 
            malesuada augue ut magna lacinia, eu scelerisque erat hendrerit. Duis mattis lorem velit, sed dictum velit
            mattis scelerisque. Fusce ut lacus eu nulla vestibulum vehicula. Pellentesque diam ante, aliquam pretium quam 
            sit amet, vestibulum mattis neque. Cras eu est tortor. Maecenas varius massa arcu, quis hendrerit nulla molestie 
            id. Maecenas non lorem ex. Morbi malesuada augue ut magna lacinia, eu scelerisque erat hendrerit. Duis mattis 
            lorem velit, sed dictum velit mattis scelerisque. Fusce ut lacus eu nulla vestibulum vehicula. Pellentesque diam ante, 
            aliquam pretium quam sit amet, vestibulum mattis neque.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. If you remove the "show" after collapse it'll work, noticed using the inspect of google :D

Answer (score 0):

I hope This will help you..i remove the show class

```
   <div class="card" id="accordion">
           <div class="card-header bg-danger">
               <a class="card-link text-dark" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne2"><span class="fas fa-newspaper solid size-1x"></span> News</a>
        </div>
            <div id="collapseOne2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
        Cras eu est tortor. Maecenas varius massa arcu, quis hendrerit nulla molestie id. Maecenas non lorem ex. Morbi 
        malesuada augue ut magna lacinia, eu scelerisque erat hendrerit. Duis mattis lorem velit, sed dictum velit
        mattis scelerisque. Fusce ut lacus eu nulla vestibulum vehicula. Pellentesque diam ante, aliquam pretium quam 
        sit amet, vestibulum mattis neque. Cras eu est tortor. Maecenas varius massa arcu, quis hendrerit nulla molestie 
        id. Maecenas non lorem ex. Morbi malesuada augue ut magna lacinia, eu scelerisque erat hendrerit. Duis mattis 
        lorem velit, sed dictum velit mattis scelerisque. Fusce ut lacus eu nulla vestibulum vehicula. Pellentesque diam ante, 
        aliquam pretium quam sit amet, vestibulum mattis neque.</div>
         </div>
      </div>
```